# SqlCeParameter and using LIKE

Tags: c#, sqlite, sql-server-ce

After searching for some time and numerous attempts, is this even supported? As seen below with the commented out attempts, I'm out of options.

Does SQL Server CE 4.0 even support the `LIKE` keyword when using parameters?

With each attempt, I noted with a comment what the out come was.

Any suggestions?

```
System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeParameter[] arrParams = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeParameter[1];
arrParams[0] = new System.Data.SqlServerCe.SqlCeParameter("@Song", "Terrapin");           

StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();

sb.Append("SELECT DISTINCT s.ID, s.Name, s.CreateDate, s.UpdateDate, l.ID AS LyricsID");
sb.Append(" FROM Songs s");
sb.Append(" LEFT JOIN Lyrics l ON l.SongID = s.ID");
// sb.Append(" WHERE Name LIKE %@Song%"); //error
// sb.Append(" WHERE Name LIKE '%'" + @Song + "'%'"); //error
// sb.Append(" WHERE Name LIKE '%@Song%'"); //no data
// sb.Append(" WHERE Name LIKE '%" + @Song + "%'"); //no data            
// sb.Append(" WHERE Name LIKE @Song"); //no data

// sb.Append(" WHERE Name = @Song"); //works if full name of song
// sb.Append(" WHERE Name LIKE '%Terrapin%'"); //works
sb.Append(" ORDER BY s.Name");            

DataTable dt = db.LoadDataTableParam(sb.ToString(), arrParams);
dataGridView1.DataSource = dt;

public DataTable LoadDataTableParam(string sql, SqlCeParameter[] paramArray)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();

    try
    {
        using (SqlCeConnection conn = new SqlCeConnection(ConnString()))
        {
            using (SqlCeCommand cmd = new SqlCeCommand(sql, conn))
            {
                cmd.Parameters.Clear();

                if(paramArray != null)
                {
                    for(int i = 0; i < paramArray.GetLength(0); i++)
                    {
                       if (paramArray[i].ParameterName != null)
                       {
                           if (paramArray[i].Value == null)
                           {
                               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramArray[i].ParameterName, DBNull.Value);
                           }
                           else
                           {
                               cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue(paramArray[i].ParameterName, paramArray[i].Value);
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }                        

               SqlCeDataAdapter sqlAdpt = new SqlCeDataAdapter();
               cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text;
               sqlAdpt.SelectCommand = cmd;
               sqlAdpt.Fill(dt);
           }
       }
   }
   catch (Exception ex)
   {
       Utilities.Forms.MsgBox.ShowBox("Error: " + ex.Message, "Error", null);
   }

   return dt;
}
```

Comment: Yes, I know it does. That's why I added "when using parameters". But someone decided to edit my post and remove that part. I put it back.

Comment: That is basically the same as doing it like this: `sb.Append(" WHERE Name LIKE '%Terrapin%'");`

Comment: Now that post I did not find and I searched a lot. Thanks.